# Connecting over WDS - strange issue

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have been struggling with the problem for a few days and have fixed most of it. Here is my network setup:

[image]

Two routers connect through WDS. Both routers have machines cable-connected to them. Main router (Archer D7) is running DHCP. Secondary router (MR-3420) is just acting as an access point with no DHCP.

The only problem I'm facing right now is that Win7 machine cannot access **one of the** two Win10 machines and vice versa. Here are my facts:

1. Main router lists all 3 machines in Clients List section.
2. All machines can ping both routers as well as all other machines.
3. Win10 PC and laptop (left) can access each others' shared folders.
4. Win7 PC (right) can access laptop's shared folders but not Win10 PC. Similarly Win10 PC cannot access Win7 PC's shared folders.
5. This is a simple Workgroup setup and there is no HomeGroup running.
6. I have tried changing several options in Advanced Networking Options such as Network Discovery etc. No avail.

What else should I try?

Comment: Have you tried disabling windows firewall at both ends?

Comment: @pythonian: Yes. No difference.